# how i know which table i get from query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I build this code, I want do multi search.

Search from tables: item, store, category.

But when I do union between queries I can't do links.

- category need `category.php?id=1`
- item need `item.php?id=1`
- store need `store.php?id=1`

But when I do union I get this:

```
id | name 
----------
1 | google
2 | love 
3 | shop 

$query = '(SELECT id,name FROM `item` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT id,name FROM `category` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT id,name FROM `store` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           LIMIT 25
';
```

how i can know which table i get the information ?

thank you!

Comment: I added the MySQL tag, because the use of backticks suggests MySQL.  You should include the database tag on your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the table to the subqueries:

```
(SELECT id, name, 'item' as which FROM `item` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name, 'category' as which FROM `category` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
UNION ALL
(SELECT id, name, 'store' as which FROM `store` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%');
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: The unescaped single quotes will break OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a dummy column with the source name:

```
$query = '(SELECT "item" as table, id,name FROM `item` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT "category" AS table, id,name FROM `category` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT "store" AS table, id,name FROM `store` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           LIMIT 25
';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add it as value to your query:

```
$query = "(SELECT id,name,'item' FROM `item` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT id,name,'CATEGORY' FROM `category` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           UNION ALL
           (SELECT id,name,'STORE' FROM `store` WHERE `accepted` = '1' AND `name` LIKE '%".$search."%')
           LIMIT 25";
```

So you will know where the record comes from

Comment: You have unescaped single quotes breaking the syntax.